# How to give write permission to apache user

Tags: linux, permissions, php, chmod

I am a beginner in server management.

I am using the class.upload.php library so that users can upload files from my website.
To this, I give a full path like: uploads/gifs/90/x.gif
This path does not exist on my server but I want to create it.

My php log returns me: `PHP Warning: mkdir (): Permission denied`

If on my server as root user I create the uploads folder with `777` permissions, the library creates the rest of the path correctly when uploading a file.
User apache owns gifs/90/x.gif

From the above, I believe that the apache user does not have write permissions on the html folder.
In etc/groups I have seen that the apache belongs to the group:
`nagcmd: x: 503: nagios, apache`

The web folder on the server has the following permissions:
`drwxr-xr-x 32 root root 4096 Feb 4 17:20 html`

I want the library to be able to automatically create directories in the html folder.
What is the best way to do it?

1. Assign write permissions to others in html /:
   `drwxr-xr-wx 32 root root 4096 Feb 4 17:20 html`
2. Give permissions only to the nagcmd group so that it can write to html/
   (I don't know how to do this)
3. Others

I don't want to compromise the security of the web.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: 4. Change the owner of `html/` to the apache user (which should be called `www-data`?). Also, `chmod 777` is *never* correct and is a potential security risk.

Comment: I advise making the `html` folder immutable (not-writable). And putting logs in a different location.

Comment: Are you using word-press. It is about the only thing that is still using PHP. Consider more sane solutions: `moustache` is good. It is well defined (is not full of gotchas), it separates concerns (code logic is separate from template), is easier to use (for both novices, and experts).

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I decided to change the owner of the ```html/``` folder and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on your system. But most likely you have a user and group called `www-data`, that the server runs as.

You can only change the user if you have capability `CAP_CHOWN` (you are root).  You can add the file to group `www-data`, but you must ask the admin to add you to this group first.

If you don't have capability `CAP_CHOWN`, then you can use a file access control list.

`setfacl -R -m "g:www-data:rwX" "directory-name"`

You may need to enable access-control-list for the file-system. But this is the safest way, as it dose not need elevated privileges (except one-time to enable on FS).

Comment: Works under Ubuntu 20.04.  I did have to install acl via. 'sudo apt install acl'.  But it worked fore me